# Change Value in Excel from String to Number

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

I wrote a script in VBA where numbers from a text file will be inserted into a worksheet. After inserting the values, Excel advises me to convert the values from strings to numbers. Inside the cell, a green triangle appears. After selecting the cell, there are different options you can select to format the value inside the cell.

I also tried to convert the values to double in VBA with `CDbl(string)` but nothing happens.

Changing the `NumberFormat` also doesn't work. I tried different values in VBA and also in Excel.

I also tried to record a macro while selecting the method but there was nothing saved inside the makro.

Anybody know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: It's probably best to modify the macro (script) that puts the text file data into the sheet.  Post the code that does this and I may be able to modify it to insert as numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have taken cell A1 as an example. Also if there are decimal values then instead of `Long` use a `Double` and change the `NumberFormat` accordingly.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim clVal As Long

    With Sheet1.[a1]
        clVal = Val(.Value)
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .ClearContents
        .Formula = clVal
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Just forgot that the values inside an array contain one type. I converted it bevor inserting it but after accessing again from the loop it was a string again.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem a bit silly, but have you tried `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value`?

More generally, you can loop through myrange, assuming it is the range you want to fix:

```
For Each c in myrange
   c.Value = c.Value
Next
```